# Remove billing phone and email fields from my account edit address in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, field, account

I'm trying to remove the phone number and email from the WooCommerce My Account edit address from but it's not working. I just want to show the address without the email and the phone number in the form. How can I do this?

What I tried:

```
<div class="woocommerce-address-fields__field-wrapper">
    <?php
    unset( $address[$fields['billing_phone']] );
    foreach ( $address as $key => $field ) {
        if ( isset( $field['country_field'], $address[ $field['country_field'] ] ) ) {
            $field['country'] = wc_get_post_data_by_key( $field['country_field'], $address[ $field['country_field'] ]['value'] );
        }
        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, wc_get_post_data_by_key( $key, $field['value'] ) );
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

This comes right out of the `form-edit-address.php` file. I've put it to my child theme because I've did some other changes. So it would be the best solution to remove the field in this PHP file.

Because of the email: I think that I must do something to prevent an error when I submit the form because this field is required there. But no clue how to do this.

Comment: You add class hidden to the fields and set them to not required

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code function will remove billing phone and email fields from My account > edit address:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'remove_account_billing_phone_and_email_fields', 20, 1 );
function remove_account_billing_phone_and_email_fields( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only on my account 'edit-address'
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'edit-address' ) ){
        unset($billing_fields['billing_phone']);
        unset($billing_fields['billing_email']);
    }
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Works great! Thank you. But it doesn't remove the (optional) from some fields in this form :(

Comment: Okey one moment. I'll ask another question and post it here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53024764/remove-optional-text-in-label-on-woocommerce-from-my-accout-edit-address-in-wo

Comment: Did it. I've tried it later this day but I was not allowed because I have not so much credits. You can like my question too so I can like yours.

Comment: @Mr.Jo New question answered and both questions "liked" …